# Create always working desktop in Windows Server for automation applications

Tags: automation, windows-server-2012

For special purpose of my company I need to run automation software ("Perfect Automation in my case) and do some actions in specific software.. All works good while RDP session is alive and user is logged on to system, but as soon as I close RDP connection my automation software doesn't work.

Is it possible to enable desktop to work all time and set some resolution to it? Whenever user logged or not it would work.